# How to I simulate facebook login in ember-testing and mock fb graph data

Tags: ember-testing, ember-cli-mirage

I am writing test for my ember app. I have ember-cli-mirage installed

My Acceptance test flow consists of facebook login

```
visit('/');
  click('#btn-login');
  fillIn('#email',"mark_ourde@tfbnw.net");//label is on fb login popup
  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/access-application');
  });
```

Issue is my test does not wait for facebook login pop up and throws error unable to find 'login_form_label'

Comment: you have to somehow make the application code that opens the login promise-aware, so the test runner can wait for it. are you using a lib like torri or simple-auth?

Comment: Yes I am using ember-cli-simple-auth and torii